# I used Jsoup to get and using AsyncTask , ArrayList<String> and displayed on ListView and

Tags: android, string, listview, android-asynctask, jsoup

```
package com.example.yannews;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// URL Address
String url = "http://www.yan.vn/";
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

ListView listview;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    // Locate the Buttons in activity_main.xml
    Button titlebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.titlebutton);
    Button descbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.descbutton);


    // Capture button click
    titlebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Execute Title AsyncTask
            new Title().execute();
        }
    });

    // Capture button click
    descbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Execute Description AsyncTask
            new Description().execute();
        }
    });




}

// Title AsyncTask
private class Title extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String title;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android Basic JSoup Tutorial");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            // Connect to the web site
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            // Get the html document title
            title = document.title();
            System.out.println(title);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

//Title get works however,displaying the bunch of information is not working with me.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Set title into TextView
        TextView txttitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titletxt);
        txttitle.setText(title);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

// Description AsyncTask
private class Description extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>> {


    ArrayList<String> news = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android Basic JSoup Tutorial");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }
```

The problem is in doInBackGround , the code didn't get information but when I tested on Java project , it completely worked.

```
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        //String desc = "Những ngôi sao trẻ \"giỏi kiếm tiền\" nhất Hollywood";

            Document document = null;
            try {
                document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            for(Element e : document.select("div[class=dvSubBannerText   dvTitle15]"))

            {

                news.add(e.text());
            }
            //getString(news);
        return news;
    }
```

When debugging, I realized that news didn't contains any information.

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute( ArrayList<String> result) {
        // Set description into TextView
        ArrayAdapter<String>adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1);
        for (String temp_result : result) {

            adapter.add(temp_result);
        }
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

    }
}

// Logo AsyncTask
}
```

So the question is why I can't display the information I got from website by Jsoup to `ListView` ?
Anyone can help me with that . I really appreciate.

Comment: Did you add to your Manifest.xml the right permission? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: JFrankie : I already added that permission but it didn't worked.